# Вывести логотип по центру

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Здравствуйте. Не как не выходит вывести логотип по центру. Слева и справа должны быть ссылки, а логотип в центре. Буду благодарен за помощь.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.cover {
 /*text-align: center;*/
 position: relative;
 background: url('images/index_cover.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 color: #fff;
 height: 100vh;
}

.cover .mask{
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #333;
 opacity: 0.4;
}

#case_head {
 background: #000;
 position: relative;
 top: 15px;
}

/*.logo {
 top: 15px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
}*/

.logo {
  /*background: url('images/logo.png') no-repeat center;*/
  width: 155px;
  height: 148px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.user {
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
}

.user a {
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu {
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru-RU">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Кемпинг Рыбчино</title>

 <!-- Load fonts -->
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

 <!-- Load css styles -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

 <div class="cover">
  <div class="mask"></div>

  <div id="case_head">
   <div class="menu">
    <a href="/">меню</a>
   </div>
   
   <div class="logo">
    <img src="images/logo.png">
   </div>

   <div class="user">
    <a href="/">Войти</a>
    <a href="/">Регистрация</a>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/YWRPPm?editors=110  я вот так делал один раз - но чуток не доработал в этом раз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое - использовать flex, как в коде ниже. Но можно и без него.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.cover {
 /*text-align: center;*/
 position: relative;
 background: url('images/index_cover.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 color: #fff;
 height: 100vh;
}

.cover .mask{
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #333;
 opacity: 0.4;
}

#case_head {
 background: #000;
 position: relative;
 top: 15px;
  
  height: 148px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu {
}

.logo {
}

.user {
}
.user a {
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru-RU">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Кемпинг Рыбчино</title>

 <!-- Load fonts -->
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

 <!-- Load css styles -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

 <div class="cover">
  <div class="mask"></div>

  <div id="case_head">
   <div class="menu">
    <a href="/">меню</a>
   </div>
   
   <div class="logo">
    <img src="images/logo.png">
   </div>

   <div class="user">
    <a href="/">Войти</a>
    <a href="/">Регистрация</a>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
```